# Intechanging node roles in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, peer

Can nodes interchange roles in hyperledger fabric?
Is it possible to make an endorsing or committing peer take the role of an orderer when required?

Answer (score 1):

- Every endorsing peer is also a committing peer.
- An orderer and a peer are totally different binaries, and have completely different APIs, so - you can't have one fill the role of the other.